# UIImageView movement using pan not completely smooth

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm working on a simple image swapping app, similar to the UI of Tinder in that users swap/navigate through images using the pan gesture. There is a slight issue that I'm having which is really bugging me and I can't really understand why it is happening - as my panning method works correctly, it still seems that it isn't as "smooth" as tinder's. The animation/redrawing of the uiimageview isn't as sharp and I can't figure out why. My code is pretty text-book panning methodology:

```
-(void)HandlePan:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{


CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{[recognizer.view setCenter:(CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x+translation.x * 1.50,recognizer.view.center.y +translation.y* 1.50))];} completion:nil];

CGPoint leftOutOfBounds = CGPointMake(-160, 160);
CGPoint rightOutOfBounds = CGPointMake(480, 160);

CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:self.view];

if(_imagePreviewerTop.center.x > self.view.center.x){



    if(velocity.x > 0){
         swipeTransform = swipeTransform+.005;
        [_decisionLabel setText:@"UPVOTE"];
        [_decisionLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor successColor]];
        [_decisionLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
    else if (velocity.x < 0){
        swipeTransform = swipeTransform-.005;
    }
    [_imagePreviewerTop setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(swipeTransform)];



}
else if(_imagePreviewerTop.center.x < self.view.center.x){
    //NSLog(@"gesture went left");


    if(velocity.x < 0){
        swipeTransform = swipeTransform-.005;
        [_decisionLabel setText:@"PASS"];
        [_decisionLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor infoBlueColor]];
        [_decisionLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
    else if(velocity.x > 0){
        swipeTransform = swipeTransform+.005;
        //NSLog(@"gesture went left");

    }
    [_imagePreviewerTop setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(swipeTransform)];


}



[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
    //implement repositioning here

    if (_imagePreviewerTop.center.x <50){
        //"finger lifted on left"

        [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{_imagePreviewerTop.center = leftOutOfBounds;
        } completion:^(BOOL isFinished){
            if (isFinished == true) {
                [self changeImage:@"0"];




            }
        }];
    }


    else if (_imagePreviewerTop.center.x > 270){
        //"finger lifted on right"
        //[self.view addSubview:_upVote];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{_imagePreviewerTop.center = rightOutOfBounds;             } completion:^(BOOL isFinished){
            if (isFinished == true) {
                [self changeImage:@"1"];

            }
        }];
    }
    else{

        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{_imagePreviewerTop.center =_imagePreviewerBottom.center;[_imagePreviewerTop setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0)];swipeTransform = 0;} completion:^(BOOL isFinished){
            if (isFinished == true) {
                [_decisionLabel setText:@"start swiping!"];
                [_decisionLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor babyBlueColor]];
                [_decisionLabel setTextColor:[UIColor infoBlueColor]];

            }
        }];
    }
}


}
```

Is there anything else I should do? I have some more code underneath that deals with velocity and location of the image but I don't think that it's relevant to the issue.I've also tried some other ways of implementing the "drag" feel, but they all seem to not be 100% smooth.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: the recognizer.view setcenter is what moves the UIImageView since its the gesture that is attached tot he Iview.

Comment: Hi Roy.. To achieve UI like Tinder, have you created two UIImageViews? I am having issue implementing the swipe and rotate. Could you put up more code please.

Comment: @idev Yes, What I did was put two UIImageView's -  one dynamic one that respond to the pan gestures and can be dragged, and then one static one that is initially behind the first but displays an image. once the dynamic imageview is tossed out of the screen, i reposition it back to its original position (directly above the static imageview) and set its image to the static imageview's image, making it seems like there are two alternating imageviews but actually allowing the users only to move one. if you have more questions, email me at royherma at gmail dot com

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research, I figured out that the since I was drawing pretty complex view's using the iOS's coregraphics (rounded corners, drop shadows, etc), the solution was to set the view's 'shouldRasterize' property to YES and that fixed the problem.

Thanks and gl.

Answer (score 1):

Try animating the movement like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 
                      delay:0.0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut 
                 animations:^ {
                   [recognizer.view setCenter:CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x+translation.x * 1.50,recognizer.view.center.y +translation.y* 1.50)];
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

Comment: I've added the full method, maybe that will help understand why this is happening.